finding next/previous element with tabindex=0?
Is there a way to find the next/previous (in document order) element with tabindex="0"?
The closest I've gotten is:
                case 'Tab':
                    let item = node.closest('.listbox').nextElementSibling
                    do {
                        const focusable = item.querySelector('[tabindex="0"]')
                        if (focusable) {
                            focusable.focus()
                            break;
                        }
                        item = item.nextElementSibling
                        if (item == null) break;
                    } while (!item.querySelector('[tabindex="0"]'))
                    break;

but this stops at the parent level.

What is the relevance of listbox for your question? Is there some rule that elements with listbox CSS class have no more than one element with tabindex=0?

It's an implementation of the ARIA listbox widget (it has defined rules about tab/arrow key navigation inside and into/out-of the component).

Not quite clear what you are trying to do. Do you want to get all the selectors tabindex="0" inside .listbox?

@s.kuznetsov, no, the ARIA listbox specification (https://www.w3.org/WAI/ARIA/apg/patterns/listbox/) says that you should be able to tab into and out-of the component ("landing" on any previously focused element). Tab-ing into the component is unproblematic (by trapping the focus/in event and recording the mouse-state), (shift-)tabbing out needs to land on a "sensible" target before or after the listbox. Sensible is probably tabindex="0" elements (and?) buttons/inputs/selects/textareas...?

querySelector or similar functions already return the items in DOM traversal order. Instead of walking over them at each iteration, you can create a list of items once and return an object that increments/decrements over the selected ones:
const Items = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('[tabindex="0"]'));
const clamp = (nr) => Math.max(0, Math.min(Items.length - 1, nr));
function iterate (item) {
  let currIdx = Items.indexOf(item?.querySelector('[tabindex="0"]'));
  return {
    current: () => Items[currIdx]
    next: () => { currIdx = clamp(currIdx + 1); return Items[currIdx]},
    previous: () => { currIdx = clamp(currIdx - 1); return Items[currIdx]}
  }
}


use MutationObserver or similar mechanism to refresh the Items if document content changes.
PS: I might have syntax errors, if you post an example I will run it on that
